# In Stripe, I want to create a charge direct on connected account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Here is my code example:

```
$create_charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => round($total_amount_pass_to_stripe * 100),
    "currency" => $currency,
    "source" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    "description" => $stripe_description,
    "application_fee" => round($application_fee * 100), // amount in cents
), array("stripe_account" => $stripe_user_id));
```

In above code I've passed amount is $134.82 and application fees is $0.74

Here stripe will calculate charge on total amount as:

134.82 * 0.029 (this is international card rate) + 0.30 = 4.21

Connected account will get 134.82 - 4.21 - 0.74 = 129.87

So what I want to do is:

My connected account should get $130 and my application fees should be $0.74

So what amount should I pass to stripe to work as I expect?

I would appreciate if you could help me to work out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add $134.95 amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the formula you need to use to compute the amount in [this support article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-charge-my-stripe-fees-to-my-customers).

You want the total net amount to be:

```
  $130 + $0.74
= $130.74
```

so according to the formula, the gross amount needs to be:

```
  ($130.74 + $0.30) / (1 - 0.029)
= $131.04 / 0.971
= $134.95
```

So you need to provide the following values when [creating the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge):

```
amount = 13495
application_fee = 74
```

Stripe will take its fees as follows:

```
   $134.95 * 0.029 + $0.30
 = $3.91 + $0.30
 = $4.21
```

so the connected account will receive:

```
  $134.95 - $4.21 (Stripe's fees) - $0.74 (your application fee)
= $130
```

and you will receive your application fee: `$0.74`

Comment: Ywain - Thank you so much for your answer.